# Integrate [Paste clipboard image to file input] into FileReader function

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have a simple code which converts an image uploaded to `<input>` into Base64;

```
<input id="inp" type='file'><br>

<textarea readonly placeholder="Base64 data" id="b64" rows="6"></textarea><br>

<img id="img"></img>

<script>
function readFile() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = e.target.result;
      document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
    }); 
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
</script>
```

and here is a code that uploads pasted clipboard image to `<input>`;

```
<input type="file" id="inp" />

<script>
const form = document.getElementById("inp");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("inp");

fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  form.submit();
});

window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  fileInput.files = e.clipboardData.files;
});
</script>
```

Both codes work fine separately, but how can I convert a clipboard-pasted image into base64 data using these codes? In other words, how can I combine the two sets of codes into one? (the latter -> former) I've tried mixing the two myself but it would get stuck at the first phase.

Comment: `<img id="img"></img>` - Images don't have closing tags.